# Writing to TCP socket incomplete c++

Tags: c++, html, string, sockets

I have a HTTP server written in c++. At some point I want to process a html file which has to be sent as response to a client, and replace some predefined labels with other ones. The process goes as follows:

```
do {
    size = read(page_fd, buffer, 1024);
    /* processing buffer - replacing variables */

    std::string tmp = std::string(buffer);
    unsigned int start = 0, end;

    do {
        start = tmp.find("#{", start);
        if (start != std::string::npos && start < tmp.length()) {
            end = tmp.find("}", start + 1);
            if (end != std::string::npos && end < tmp.length()) {
                std::string tmp2 = tmp.substr(start + 2, end - start - 2);

                tmp = tmp.replace(start, end - start + 1, params[tmp2.c_str()]);

                start = end + 1;
            }
        }
    } while (start != std::string::npos && start > end && start < tmp.length());

    char buff[512];
    memcpy(buff, tmp.c_str(), tmp.length());
    std::cout << buff << "\n\n";

    /* end of processing - writing to socket */
    write(_conn_fd, buff, tmp.length());
} while (size > 0);
```

The html page I want to send to the client is this one:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Index</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>It works!</h1>
        <h2>#{custom}</h2>
            <p>This page was served through a C++ HTTP server!</p>
   </body>
   </html>
```

When checking what the client has received, the html code is always incomplete, as follows:

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <title>Index</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>It works!</h1>
        <h2>replaced message</h2>
            <p>This page was served through a C++ HTTP server!</p>
```

The `std::cout` line in the code outputs the correct html string.

Why does the client not receive the complete html, or if it receives it completely, why isn't that visible from a browser?

Comment: `std::string tmp = std::string(buffer);` is broken. This constructor for `std::string` requires a pointer to a C-style string, which `buffer` isn't. At this point, `size` contains the number of bytes you received and nothing else does. How could the constructor know how big the string should be?

Comment: buffer is a C-style string. it is defined as `char buffer[1024]`. Afrer the `do {} while`, the `buff` variable contains the desired output.

Comment: It's not a C-style string. It's just a character array. How should the constructor know how many bytes the string should be? (Do you know what a C-style string is? How does `strlen` tell how long a C-style string is?) In your code, `size` is the *only* thing that contains the number of bytes of data you received, and you don't use it except to know when the connection has closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it! It was the content-length which was set before the parsing and replacing. After the parsing, the length of the string changed, but the content-length remained the same. Silly me!

Answer (score 0):

Your buffer is only 512 bytes in size, but you are sending tmp.length() * 5 which is = 1040 by my calculation. So write will be reading off the end of your buffer, causing bad things to happen.

Also you should be doing a strncpy instead of a memcpy as strncpy will include the trailing null, whereas your memcpy will exclude the null and just leave the buffer as it was, which means it could be putting anything in there, causing your output to be random.

Comment: Sorry, initially it was only `tmp.length()`.

Comment: In which case it should be tmp.length()+1 to include the null character at the end. I would `memset(buff, 0, sizeof(buff));` after declaring the buffer and use strncpy. You should add a check the make sure tmp.length is never greater than your buffer size. Or just make your buffer size a lot bigger.

Comment: In this particular example which is posted in the question body, the buffer size is a lot bigger, so it should have worked fine. If I write to a file the same buff, the output is correct.